# 404 not found , Symfony routing path problem

Tags: php, symfony, path, routes

i create a controller pageController.php :

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class pageController {

    public function index()
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>hello...</body></html>');
    }
    public function contactAction()
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>contact...</body></html>');
    }

}
```

and here is the routes.yml

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\pageController::index

contact:
    path: /contact
    controller: App\Controller\pageController::contactAction
```

the index works fine, but the contact doesn't work!

**Note: when I changed the path of index from "/" to "/index", it doesn't work anymore, it shows 404 not found**

I don't want to use annotations until  i want to fix this

Answer (score 1):

```
contact:
    path: /contact
    controller: App\Controller\pageController::contact
```

Symfony will look for your contact*Action* you don't need to mention it in your YML

Ps: you don't call a route by a route name /index wont work but you call it by the path */*

Comment: I call it by the path !  which is '/contact'  but 404 not found problem appear

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of symfony you are using, but if it is symfony 2.x then you should name your index method as index**Action** (exactly like you have in contact).

routes.yml:

```
index:
path: /
controller: App\Controller\pageController::indexAction
```

controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
     return new Response('<html><body>hello...</body></html>');
}
```

You should also make sure that your routes.yml are properly loaded.

Comment: but the index works fine . if i change the path of index from ' / '  to ' /page' or any other path ,and i type /page , i get 404 not found prob! i am using symfony 5